# ng:areq : While resolving data Angular UI Modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

I got some data passing from a controller to modal's controller.

In my controller:

```
        vm.timetableModal = modals.open.timetable(vm.store.formatted_working_hours || null);
        vm.timetableModal.result.then(function (res) {
            vm.store.formatted_working_hours = res.formatted_working_hours;
        })
```

In modals factory:

```
function timetable(current_working_hours) {
            return $uibModal.open({
                templateUrl: 'templates/modals/timetable_modal.html',
                controller: 'timeTableCtrl',
                controllerAs: 'tm',
                resolve: {
                    current_working_hours: current_working_hours
                }
            });
        }
```

The problem occurs when `current_working_hours` is not null.

The actual error is:

> "Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/ng/areq?p0=fn&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20Object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had to do it this way:

```
resolve: {
            current_working_hours: function() {
               return current_working_hours;
         }
```

Instead of this:

```
resolve: {
            current_working_hours: current_working_hours
         }
```